# C++ - How can I delegate all member functions invocations on a class to a member of the same interface

Tags: c++, c++11, delegates, perfect-forwarding

I have an interface and a couple of classes that implement that interface.

I also have a class which simply acts as a wrapper that simply delegates all calls to a member that also implements that interface.

```
#include <iostream>

class IFoo {
public:
    virtual void a() = 0;
    virtual int b(int) = 0;
    virtual bool c() = 0;
};

class Foo : public IFoo {
public:
    void a() override { std::cout << "Foo::a" << std::endl; };
    int b(int x) override { std::cout << "Foo::b" << std::endl;};
    bool c() override { std::cout << "Foo::c" << std::endl; };
};

class Foo2 : public IFoo {
public:
    void a() override { std::cout << "Foo2::a" << std::endl; };
    int b(int x) override { std::cout << "Foo2::b" << std::endl;};
    bool c() override { std::cout << "Foo2::c" << std::endl; };
};

class DelegatingFoo : public IFoo {
public:
    DelegatingFoo(IFoo* f) : foo(f) {}

    void a() override { return foo->a(); }
    int b(int x) override { return foo->b(x); }
    bool c() override { return foo->c(); }
private:
    IFoo* foo;
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    DelegatingFoo dfoo(&foo);
    dfoo.a();
    dfoo.b(5);
    dfoo.c();

    Foo2 foo2;
    DelegatingFoo dfoo2(&foo2);
    dfoo2.a();
    dfoo2.b(5);
    dfoo2.c();
}
```

I was wondering if I could simply forward the calls from DelegatingFoo to it's foo member, without having to define all the overridden methods, so that if I make a change to the IFoo interface, I would not need to change the DelegatingFoo class at all.

In my case, the DelegatingFoo class is acting as a base class for other wrappers, so that those wrappers don't have to re-implement all the forwarded methods again.

Comment: Depends on why does `DelegatingFoo` exist, what does it add ? what's the intended difference between `DelegatingFoo` and `Foo` ?

Comment: In my case, it is acting as a base class for other wrappers, so that they don't have to re-implement all these functions again.

Comment: Why not directly inherit from `Foo` ? Currently your `DelagatingFoo` is basicaly just a pointer on `Foo`

Comment: I've wanted to do this a few times and come to the conclusion that you can't. I think the most convenient way is to write a script that generates the delegating class.

Comment: @Drax `Foo` might have some things that I don't want to expose to the `DelegatingFoo` class. Also there may be multiple implementations of the `IFoo` class that the `DelegatingFoo` class should wrap.

Comment: Then as far as i know you have to do it the way you started, you might use private inheritance to improve a little bit the syntax but nothing too impactful, as long as you can't expose all the public interface of the class you are adapting/proxying/facading you can't automate it

Answer (score 0):

One could write a macro that looked like

```
DEFINE_METHOD( SCOPE, NAME, RETURN_TYPE, ARG0_TYPE, ARG1_TYPE, ARG2_TYPE )
```

then

```
DECLARE_INTERFACE( SCOPE, NAME )
IMPLEMENT_FORWARD( SCOPE, NAME, TARGET )
```

but you shouldn't.

And I won't teach you how.  If you want to know how others have done something similar, go master boost's preprocessor library.  The hacks are beyond evil, the code is worse, and the result is difficult to maintain and nearly impossible to debug.

Now, there is work underway to add reflection and reification to the C++ standard.  Reflection is likely to arrive first, in C++20 or C++2* something.  Reification may occur later.  What you want appears to require both.

Reflection is where you can operate on compile-time data structures like interfaces in C++ (they plan to do this at compile-time as well).  Reification is where you generate new C++ code, possibly based off reflection information.